# Meaning of Salilā (सलिला)

Tags: vedas

My teacher gave me the name Salilā (सलिला). The meaning given was "a flowing river that gives life to all living beings". Can anyone share meaning in relation to the Veda's?

Comment: The word  Salilā (सलिला) is used in the The Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad as a example of Brahman , he himself is witness  alone (no second)  . Just like water is transparent but it itself is reflection of itself , and ultimately to convey us that Brahman alone exists See Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad 4.3.32

Comment: Pure Sanskrit language questions are off-topic here.

Comment: So if I ask "What is the meaning of the word Purusha in the context of the Vedas?" will that be off-topic? Here the Q is similar .  It is not simply asking the meaning of a word.. @Pandya

Comment: @Rickross No, s/he should provide context. Here it seems OP just want to know meaning of his name.

Comment: Btw OP has mentioned this " in relation to the Vedas"  @Pandya

Comment: @Rickross Let me clear: If s/he had asked What is the meaning of xyz word in particular verse, then it could be fine. But here s/he just tried to connect word with Vedas.

Comment: This looks dictionary question. Let's continue in chat-room.

Comment: Ok but I thought swiftpushkar knew an interesting answer which mite be useful .. @Pandya but anyways it's alright ..

Comment: No I don't agree that it is a dictionary Q .. it is  slightly different from that .. anyways let's end the discussion here @Pandya